# Add child of child to python xml

Tags: python, xml

I create a code which writes the data to xml file.But it is not working properly. It gives a error called "TypeError: must be Element, not None
"

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder

class create_xml:
  def __init__(self):
      pass


def write_xml(predicted_list, image_list):

   print predicted_list
   print image_list
   i = 0
   root = ET.Element("video_data")

   for image in image_list:
     doc = ET.SubElement(root, 'frame').set('name', image)
     predicted_item = predicted_list[i]
     ET.SubElement(doc, predicted_item) **Gives error in here**
     # doc.text = predicted_list[i]
     i += 1

 tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
 tree.write("/opt/lampp/htdocs/video_frames/test.xml")
```

I need the out put as below,

```
<video_data>
  <frame name="">
   <predicted_item>output</predicted_item>
  </frame>
</video_data>
```

But without the error occuring code segment it gives the output as below:

```
 <video_data><frame name="/opt/lampp/htdocs/video_frames/bb/frame48.jpg" /></video_data>
```

please help me to solve this, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `doc` becomes `None` since it equals to the result of `set()` call. Instead, you meant to have `doc` pointing to the `SubElement` instance:

```
doc = ET.SubElement(root, 'frame')
doc.set('name', image)
```

Comment: Thank you alecuxe. Now it is working. The working code is,
    root = ET.Element("video_data")

    for image in image_list:
        doc = ET.SubElement(root, 'frame')
        doc.set('name', image)
        # predicted_item = predicted_list[i]
        subdoc = ET.SubElement(doc, 'object_name')
        subdoc.text = predicted_list[i]
        i += 1